# Schedule Report in CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a report in crm 2011.
Now
want to schedule it for last 24 hours.
and then download as pdf and save it a folder.

how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following articles. In case you will have further questions, don't hesitate to ask.
http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2012/11/general-approaches-to-generation-of.html
http://edwardsdna.com/2009/07/17/creating-report-subscriptions-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4/